# Problem with run PGAdmin in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I have a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
 version: "3.9"
     
 services:
   db:
     image: postgres
     volumes:
       - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
       - ./mysqlfile.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysqlfile.sql
     environment:
       - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
       - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

   pgadmin:
     image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.18
     restart: always
     environment:
       - [PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@linuxhint.com]
       - [PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: secret]
       - [PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80]
     ports:
       - "8090:80"
     volumes:
       - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
     links:
       - "db:pgsql-server"
     volumes:
 
   web:
     build: .
     command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
     volumes:
       - .:/code
     ports:
       - "8000:8000"
     depends_on:
       - db
```

When I try to use `docker-compose up` command I have error like this:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.pgadmin.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be an array
```

When I remove second `volumes` from `pgadmin` section a new error appers:

```
Named volume "pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin:rw" is used in service "pgadmin" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

How can I fix this error to run my container correctly?

Comment: Can you please double check your pasted file because it already contains an indentation error on the third line which should lead to a totally different error. So I'm not sure the file we see is the the one you actually ran. It is impossible to spot an error related to yaml syntax if you did not paste the exact file your are using.

Comment: @Zeitounator I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `volumes` two times in `pgadmin`, remove the empty one. Then declare it at the bottom:

```
...
  ports:
    - "8090:80"
  volumes:
    - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
  links:
    - "db:pgsql-server"
volumes:
  pgadmin-data:
```

Note that `volumes:` is not indented like `links:`

Comment: When I remove it, new error appears: `Named volume "pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin:rw" is used in service "pgadmin" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.`

Comment: @tryToCompileThis I updated my answer to address this issue.

Comment: @tryToCompileThis You would benefit spending some time on the documentation. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes